# tasking previously default value from the text box not taking edit value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I edit the value in the `ProjectName` input the value is going in projects object is same it wil 
not take my edit value it will take default previoeuslly value.

```html
<td class="ProjectName">
  <span>@item.ProjectName</span>
  <input type="text" style="display: none" value="@item.ProjectName" />
</td>
```

```js
var projects = {};
projects.ID = row.find(".ID").find("span").html();
projects.ProjectName = row.find(".ProjectName").find("span").html();
projects.ProjectDescription = row.find(".ProjectDescription").find("span").html();
projects.StartDate = row.find(".StartDate").find("span").html();
projects.EndDate = row.find(".EndDate").find("span").html();
console.log(projects)
```

Comment: your input is set as `style="display:none"`, so it must be invisible then how are you entering value in it? Please share some more details like when you are executing jquery code and overall table structure

Comment: This is presumably because you only set the properties of your `projects` object when the page loads. You need to use a `input` event handler if you want to update the values as the user types. There are thousands of questions and tutorials covering this if you take the time to research

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar it is invisible when i am using append row function..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i make a projects object to send data into ajax but the data that i edit into the textboxs are not gone previously value are gone in the projects object.it will not take my edit value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: you are trying to read `span` text instead of `input` hence not getting edited value. Please use below code to read input value

```
projects.ProjectName = row.find(".ProjectName").find("input").val();
```

Note: You can give specific id to input **(must be unique in DOM)** so that if table structure get changes in future you will need not to modify your script and it will read correct input value only.

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" value="@item.ProjectName" id="projectName" />

projects.ProjectName = $("#projectName").val();
```